# Maximum number of epochs and validation frequency in deep learning networks

Tags: neural-networks, matlab

I read in one article that the number of epochs in a deep learning network are varied according to a validation frequency of 300. I am not sure what it means. Does it mean after every 300 weight updates, a round of validation is performed? Also how are epochs related to that, as epoch count stays fixed. What is the relation between the maximum number of epochs and the validation frequency?

Comment: Please provide the exact quote and a link to the article. The context is often useful in disambiguating or interpreting the quote, without having users go through a noisy channel decoding problem.

Comment: By the way, your two paragraphs are about unrelated things. If you have two questions, it’s better to post them here as two separate posts, instead of one combined one.

Comment: I read many articles, and unfortunately I can not find that one. In general, I am asking about the relation between the maximum number of epochs and the validation frequency?

Comment: I will post the second paragraph as a separate question.